Camera Enable/ Disable option is not present in Raspberry pi

Camera Enable/ Disable option is not present in Raspberry pi 3 B+ model 
Camera module : Raspberry pi camera rev1.3
os :
uname -a
Linux dharanikanna 6.6.62+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.62-1+rpt1 (2024-11-25) aarch64 GNU/Linux
Ensured that Pi board and camera connection is also correct.
Below command used and bet the corresponding output
cmd : vcgencmd get_camera
output : supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
I have tried to do upgrade the packages, even no use.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
Please help to enable camera option in raspberry pi.

I have found this "Legacy camera subsystem removed from 64-bit RPi OS (still available on 32-bit)" from raspberry pi release notes. What ever os am uisng is 23bit version only
Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and recommended software
Release date: November 19th 2024
System: 32-bit
Kernel version: 6.6
Debian version: 12 (bookworm)
Size: 2,727MB

Have you read this? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=362707

Hi Thank you @CoderMike this doc helped me to narrow down the issue 
I have followed the below commands to sort-out and fix the issue
Device Conflict Resolution: Ensure no other processes are using /dev/video0 before starting a new application.
Use lsof /dev/video0 to identify active processes.
Use sudo kill -9  to terminate those processes if necessary.
Testing Camera Functionality:
libcamera-hello confirms the camera is functioning as expected.

@DHARANIKANNA why are you writing a comment on your own question? ... please update the question if you wish to add information
